# How to compute hamming code for 10 bits?

Tags: bit, error-correction, error-detection, hamming-code

I have seen examples of hamming code detection and correction with 8 bits or 12 bits. Suppose I had the bit string: `1101 0110 11` which contains 10 bits.

Do I need to add two additional bits to that bit string to complete the nibble? If so do I add `0s or 1s`?

I have looked for other examples, but cannot seem to find those with partial nibbles to determine the procedure. Thank you.